# Visual studio : Remove and sort using except the System reference

Tags: visual-studio-2008, refactoring

When I use the option : Organize Usings -> Remove and sort from Visual Studio 2008 I would like to clear all unused references but to keep some like System; Is there an option I can set to do that ?

Comment: yes, ... that would be really cool

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seems to exists ... for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is not.

If you really need it, perhaps you could build your own plugin for Visual Studio to do it.

Comment: Or just do the remove and sort at the very very end of your project. . .

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to keep your unused references is to reference them in your code, unfortunately.